How can I prefill DatePicker and TimePicker components with data retrieved from the backend?
I'm working on React app using Ant-Design UI library. I am trying to prefill the date and time pickers with data received from backend so users can change the dates/time and make an API call to update. I used the form.setFieldsValue inside useEffect to set the date and time picker values with form passed as dependency into the useEffect. I noticed that the date picker were blinking as a result it was difficult to select date/time. On the other hand, I removed the dependency array and the form fields were not prefilled with data.
useEffect(() => {
  const data = openHours?.data?.data;
  form.setFieldsValue({
    firsTermFrom:
      openHours?.data?.data?.firstTerm?.from &&
      moment(openHours?.data?.data?.firstTerm?.from, dateFormat).isValid()
        ? moment(openHours?.data?.data?.firstTerm?.from, dateFormat)
        : "",
    firstTermTo:
      openHours?.data?.data?.firstTerm?.to &&
      moment(data?.firstTerm?.to, dateFormat).isValid()
        ? moment(openHours?.data?.data?.firstTerm?.to, dateFormat)
        : "",
    secondTermFrom:
      openHours?.data?.data?.secondTerm?.from &&
      moment(data?.secondTerm?.from, dateFormat).isValid()
        ? moment(openHours?.data?.data?.secondTerm?.from, dateFormat)
        : "",
    secondTermTo:
      openHours?.data?.data?.secondTerm?.to &&
      moment(data?.secondTerm?.to, dateFormat).isValid()
        ? moment(openHours?.data?.data?.secondTerm?.to, dateFormat)
        : "",
    thirdTermFrom:
      openHours?.data?.data?.thirdTerm?.from &&
      moment(data?.thirdTerm?.from, dateFormat).isValid()
        ? moment(openHours?.data?.data?.thirdTerm?.from, dateFormat)
        : "",
    thirdTermTo:
      openHours?.data?.data?.thirdTerm?.to &&
      moment(data?.thirdTerm?.to, dateFormat).isValid()
        ? moment(openHours?.data?.data?.thirdTerm?.to, dateFormat)
        : "",
    studentStart:
      openHours?.data?.data?.studentsNewResumptionTime !== "Invalid date" &&
      openHours?.data?.data?.studentsNewResumptionTime !== null &&
      moment(data?.studentsNewResumptionTime, "h:mm:ss a").isValid()
        ? moment(
          openHours?.data?.data?.studentsNewResumptionTime,
          "h:mm:ss a"
        ) : "",
    studentEnd:
      openHours?.data?.data?.studentNewClosingTime !== "Invalid date" &&
      openHours?.data?.data?.studentNewClosingTime !== null &&
      moment(data?.studentNewClosingTime, "h:mm:ss a").isValid()
        ? moment(openHours?.data?.data?.studentNewClosingTime, "h:mm:ss a")
        : "",
    superStart:
      openHours?.data?.data?.supervisorNewResumptionTime !== "Invalid date" &&
      openHours?.data?.data?.supervisorNewResumptionTime !== null &&
      moment(data?.supervisorNewResumptionTime, "h:mm:ss a").isValid()
        ? moment(
          openHours?.data?.data?.supervisorNewResumptionTime,
          "h:mm:ss a"
        ) : "",
    superEnd:
      openHours?.data?.data?.supervisorNewClosingTime &&
      openHours?.data?.data?.supervisorNewClosingTime !== "Invalid date" &&
      openHours?.data?.data?.supervisorNewClosingTime !== null &&
      moment(data?.supervisorNewClosingTime, "h:mm:ss a").isValid()
        ? moment(openHours?.data?.data?.supervisorNewClosingTime, "h:mm:ss a")
        : "",
  });
}, []);

<Form
  className="openHrs w-2/3"
  form={form}
  title="open-hours"
  onFinish={onFinish}
  onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
  autoComplete="off"
>
  <div className="">
    <span
      className="text-lg font-extrabold"
      title="openhrs"
      data-testid="openhrs-title"
    >
      Open hours
    </span>
  </div>

  {/* SESSION */}
  <div className="mt-7 mb-3 flex flex-col items-baseline">
    <div className="mb-7 w-60">
      <span className="student font-InterMedium text-base font-medium tracking-widest text-arshGrey opacity-100">
        SESSION
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  {/* TERMS */}
  <div className="flex flex-col space-y-3">
    {/* 1ST TERM*/}
    <div className="mt-2 mb-1 flex flex-row items-baseline space-x-12">
      <div className="mb-7 w-1/4">
        <span className="font-InterMedium text-base font-medium">
          First term
        </span>
      </div>

      {/* RESUMPTION TIME */}
      <div className="flex w-3/4 flex-row items-center space-x-2">
        <Form.Item
          name={"firsTermFrom"}
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Please input first term start date",
            },
          ]}
        >
          <DatePicker
            picker="date"
            className="openInput outline-0 w-52 rounded border-0 bg-inputBg px-10 py-3 font-InterMedium opacity-100 shadow-none"
            placeholder="Start date"
            format={dateFormat}
            size={"large"}
            data-testid="first-term-from"
          />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item
          name={"firstTermTo"}
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Please input second term start date",
            },
          ]}
        >
          <DatePicker
            picker="date"
            className="openInput outline-0 w-52 rounded border-0 bg-inputBg px-10 py-3 font-InterMedium opacity-100 shadow-none"
            placeholder="End date"
            format={dateFormat}
            size={"large"}
          />
        </Form.Item>
      </div>
    </div>

    {/* 2ND TERM */}
    <div className="mb-3 flex flex-row items-baseline space-x-12">
      <div className="mb-7 w-1/4">
        <span className="schName font-InterMedium text-base font-medium">
          Second term
        </span>
      </div>

      {/* RESUMPTION TIME */}
      <div className="flex w-3/4 flex-row items-baseline space-x-2">
        <Form.Item
          name={"secondTermFrom"}
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Please input second term start date",
            },
          ]}
        >
          <DatePicker
            picker="date"
            className="openInput outline-0 w-52 rounded border-0 bg-inputBg px-10 py-3 font-InterMedium opacity-100 shadow-none"
            placeholder="Start date"
            format={dateFormat}
            size={"large"}
          />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item
          name={"secondTermTo"}
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Please input second term end date",
            },
          ]}
        >
          <DatePicker
            picker="date"
            className="openInput outline-0 w-52 rounded border-0 bg-inputBg px-10 py-3 font-InterMedium opacity-100 shadow-none"
            placeholder="End date"
            format={dateFormat}
            size={"large"}
          />
        </Form.Item>
      </div>
    </div>

    {/* 3RD TERM */}
    <div className="mb-3 flex flex-row items-baseline space-x-12">
      <div className="mb-7 w-1/4">
        <span className="schName font-InterMedium text-base font-medium">
          Third term
        </span>
      </div>

      {/* RESUMPTION TIME */}
      <div className="flex w-3/4 flex-row items-center space-x-2">
        <Form.Item
          name={"thirdTermFrom"}
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Please input third term start date",
            },
          ]}
        >
          <DatePicker
            picker="date"
            className="openInput outline-0 w-52 rounded border-0 bg-inputBg px-10 py-3 font-InterMedium opacity-100 shadow-none"
            placeholder="Start date"
            format={dateFormat}
            size={"large"}
          />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item
          name={"thirdTermTo"}
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Please input third term end date",
            },
          ]}
        >
          <DatePicker
            picker="date"
            className="openInput outline-0 w-52 rounded border-0 bg-inputBg px-10 py-3 font-InterMedium opacity-100 shadow-none"
            placeholder="Start date"
            format={dateFormat}
            size={"large"}
          />
        </Form.Item>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  {/* HORIZONTAL RULE */}
  <hr className="mt-7 w-5/6 p-1" />

  {/* STUDENT */}
  <div className="mt-7 mb-3 flex flex-col items-baseline">
    <div className="mb-7 w-60">
      <span className="student font-InterMedium text-base font-medium tracking-widest text-arshGrey opacity-100">
        STUDENT
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  {/* STUDENT TIMES */}
  <div className="flex flex-col">
    {/* RESUMPTION */}
    <div className="mt-2 mb-1 flex flex-row items-baseline space-x-12">
      <div className="mb-7 w-1/4">
        <span className="font-InterMedium text-base font-medium">
          Resumption time
        </span>
      </div>

      {/* RESUMPTION TIME */}
      <Form.Item
        className="w-3/4"
        name={"studentStart"}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input student resumption time",
          },
        ]}
      >
        <TimePicker
          use12Hours
          format="h:mm:ss a"
          className="openInput outline-0 focus:outline-none h-12 w-2/3 rounded border-0 bg-inputBg px-10 py-5 font-InterMedium opacity-100 shadow-none placeholder:font-InterMedium"
          placeholder="Resumption time"
          size={"large"}
        />
      </Form.Item>
    </div>

    {/* CLOSING */}
    <div className="mb-3 flex flex-row items-baseline space-x-12">
      <div className="mb-7 w-1/4">
        <span className="schName font-InterMedium text-base font-medium">
          Closing time
        </span>
      </div>

      {/* RESUMPTION TIME */}
      <Form.Item
        className="w-3/4"
        name={"studentEnd"}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input student closing time",
          },
        ]}
      >
        <TimePicker
          use12Hours
          format="h:mm:ss a"
          className="openInput outline-0 focus:outline-none h-12 w-2/3 rounded border-0 bg-inputBg px-10 py-5 font-InterMedium opacity-100 shadow-none placeholder:font-InterMedium"
          placeholder="Closing time"
          size={"large"}
        />
      </Form.Item>
    </div>
  </div>

  {/* HORIZONTAL RULE */}
  <hr className="w-5/6 p-1" />

  {/* TEACHERS */}
  <div className="mt-4 mb-3 flex flex-col items-baseline">
    <div className="mb-4 w-60">
      <span className="font-InterMedium text-base font-medium tracking-widest text-arshGrey opacity-100">
        TEACHERS
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  {/* TEACHERS RESUMPTION TIME */}
  <div className="flex flex-col">
    {/* RESUMPTION */}
    <div className="mt-2 mb-1 flex flex-row items-baseline space-x-12">
      <div className="mb-7 w-1/4">
        <span className="schName font-InterMedium text-base font-medium">
          Resumption time
        </span>
      </div>

      {/* RESUMPTION TIME */}
      <Form.Item
        className="w-3/4"
        name={"superStart"}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input teacher resumption time",
          },
        ]}
      >
        <TimePicker
          use12Hours
          format="h:mm:ss a"
          className="openInput outline-0 focus:outline-none h-12 w-2/3 rounded border-0 bg-inputBg px-10 py-5 font-InterMedium opacity-100 shadow-none placeholder:font-InterMedium"
          placeholder="Resumption time"
          size={"large"}
          name="resumptionTime"
        />
      </Form.Item>
    </div>

    {/* CLOSING */}
    <div className="mb-3 flex flex-row items-baseline space-x-12">
      <div className="mb-7 w-1/4">
        <span className="schName font-InterMedium text-base font-medium">
          Closing time
        </span>
      </div>

      {/* RESUMPTION TIME */}
      <Form.Item
        className="w-3/4"
        name={"superEnd"}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input teacher closing time",
          },
        ]}
      >
        <TimePicker
          use12Hours
          format="h:mm:ss a"
          className="openInput outline-0 focus:outline-none h-12 w-2/3 rounded border-0 bg-inputBg px-10 py-5 font-InterMedium opacity-100 shadow-none placeholder:font-InterMedium"
          placeholder="Closing time"
          size={"large"}
        />
      </Form.Item>
    </div>

    <Button
      className="save float-right  h-8 w-auto cursor-pointer place-self-end rounded border border-solid border-regularGreen bg-regularGreen font-InterBold font-medium text-regularWhite opacity-100"
      htmlType="submit"
      size="middle"
      loading={loading}
    >
      {openHrsId === undefined || "" ? "CREATE" : "EDIT"}{" "}
    </Button>
  </div>

  {/* SAVE */}
  <div className="text-end w-full pb-7 text-right"></div>
</Form>


Which version of ant design are you using?

I use antd version 5.x

Ant design 5 is using Dayjs library for date and time.
You can replace it with moment js, did you do that?
Read here
https://ant.design/docs/react/use-custom-date-library

yeah i did that already

I think if you add openHours?.data?.data to the useEffect dependency it will be solved.

I found a solution to it. i'd post it here shortly
